# Can I revise/edit the custom message on bounty question?

Tags: feature-request, support, bounties, bounty-remarks

When we apply bounty on question, The following dialogue box provides to add custom message (optional):

[image: screenshot]

After bounty applied, This message is shown as bottom line of bounty information.

Now, If I want to edit/revise/add that custom message, then How do I do that? or Is it not allowed/permitted?

Comment: Oh! I was unaware of tag:[tag:bounty-remarks], Othewise [That was Highest Voted Question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bounty-remarks?sort=votes)!